# Implement condition plugin

Tags: 8, plugins

```
namespace Drupal\my_block\Plugin\Condition;

use Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionPluginBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
* Provides a 'Company' condition.
*
* @Condition(
*   id = "company",
*   label = @Translation("Company"),
*   context = {
*     "company" = @ContextDefinition("company", label =   @Translation("Company"))
*   }
* )
*
*/
class Company extends ConditionPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
  private $request;
  public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $request, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->request = $request->getCurrentRequest();
  }
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
    $container->get('request_stack'), $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition
    );
  }
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $company_options = [0 => "COM1", 1 => "COM2", 2 => "COM3"];
    $form['company'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => $this->t('Company selection'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['company'],
      '#options' => $company_options,
      '#description' => $this->t('Select company to enforce. If none are selected, all companies will be allowed.'),
    );
    return $form;
  //return parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
  }
    public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['company'] = array_filter($form_state->getValue('company'));
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function summary() {
    return t('This is a summary');
  }

  public function evaluate() {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

The evaluate function keeps returning false(my guess). Since when I enable the context in the block the block disappears no matter what. Even though my evaluate function returns TRUE. Any idea what's wrong here?
I've taken this from the Language condition implementation.

Comment: What's the company context, where does it come from?

Comment: It will be coming from the request as a parameter on the url. It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Then it is not a context, remove it. Contexts are explicity defined things. The fact that block UI even shows your condition when the required contexts are missing is a bug.

Comment: This solved it :-) Wanta make it an answer?